# Давайте добавим [collections] синонимом к метке [коллекции]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Давайте добавим [collections](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collections) синонимом к метке [коллекции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8).

Comment: @Nick а почему я не вижу еще что синоним утверждён? Кэш?

Comment: @alexolut забыл нажать «Подтвердить». )